# create SNS topic in specific region

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sns

I am trying to create SNS topic in a specific region using cloudformation template.

```
SNSTopic:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
    Properties: 
      FifoTopic: True
      TopicName: <topicname>.fifo

  SNSTopicPolicy:
    Type: AWS::SNS::TopicPolicy
    Properties:
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: 's3.amazonaws.com'
            Action: sns:Publish
            Resource: !Ref SNSTopic
            Condition:
              ArnEquals:
                aws:SourceArn: 'arn'
              StringEquals:
                aws:SourceAccount: <accountId>
```

I don't any parameter for mentioning region, where can I mention the region. I found for subscription I can mention the region for cross region resources but how do I create SNS topic in specific region using cloudformation template(yaml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to create a [stack set](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/stacksets-getting-started-create.html) for your topic and specify the region in its `StackInstancesGroup`.

You won't be able to use the stack set output, so you'll have to hardcode the topic ARN if you are going to use it in the main template.

Comment: I have other resources too which are created in default region, I am thinking of creating separate stacks and deploy them in different region If there is nothing specific to mention region name for SNS.

Comment: That's exactly the problem stack sets solve. You can create multiple stack sets for different regions within a single template